# How to handle data with no space between separators when using fread in R

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.table

I am reading a large `.txt` file (>1GB) into `R` via `fread`. I am reading the file in directly from a `.zip` archive, via a bash command:

```
base = fread('unzip -p Folder.zip File.txt', sep = '|', header = FALSE, 
stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings="", quote = "", col.names = col_namesMain)
```

The text file separates entries via `|` so that a typical line might look like:

```
RRX|||02020||333293||||12123
```

However, there are many places where empty entries are denoted by separators with no space between them, e.g. `||` in the example line above.

When using `fread`, these adjacent separators are typically read in altogether, so that the above line returns the following entries:

```
RRX, ||02020|, 333293|||, 12123
```

when it should read in as:

```
RRX, NA, NA, 02020, NA, 333293, NA, NA, NA, 12123
```

I have tried using `read.table` with the option `skipNul = TRUE`, and this works perfectly. However, there doesn't seem to be any option similar to `skipNul` for `fread`. I would much prefer to use `fread` over `read.table` if possible, since I have several very large files. Despite my searching, I haven't come across much discussion of this problem. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I can't replicate this issue. `fread("RRX|||02020||333293||||12123\n", sep="|")` gives me `RRX NA NA 2020 NA 333293 NA NA NA 12123` as a result.

Comment: @Frank Ah, yes, that is what I mean, thanks.

Comment: @thelatemail I also find that the line reads in correctly using the command `fread("RRX|||02020||333293||||12123\n", sep="|")`. However, I continue to have the problem when using `fread` on the `unzip` bash command. Perhaps the problem is with the way I'm reading the text file from the zip archive?

Comment: You want `||` to be read in as two NA's? Is `,` a delimiter here?

Comment: Tried with zipped file, works correctly for me. Maybe missing '\n' in your zipped file? Try unzipping and reading unzipped file from disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have tried using read.table with the option skipNul = TRUE, and this
>   works perfectly. However, there doesn't seem to be any option similar
>   to skipNul for fread.

This has been fixed in dev 1.12.3 on 15 Apr 2019 (see [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md)) :

> 3. fread() now skips embedded NUL (\0), #3400. Thanks to Marcus Davy for reporting with examples, and Roy Storey for the initial PR.